# Como lidar com as regras de negócio?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, design-pattern, prism

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação C# WPF + EF6 e me encontro perdido na hora de reaproveitar as regras de negócios.

Estou usando o padrão de repositório + unit of work, mas acredito que copiar-colar filtros complexos nas minhas chamadas ao repositório me parece ser uma ideia ruim... Então decidi mover as regras de negócio para uma nova camada, mas alguma coisa ainda não está me parecendo bem... Atualmente tenho as seguintes camadas:

**ViewModel**: Onde ocorre a lógica de interação com a View e a validação

**BLL**: Camada criada para tentar contornar o problema acima, ela é responsável por compor a lógica de busca/adição/remoção de uma entidade.

**DAL** (Padrão de repositório+UOF): Aqui apenas persisto o POCO no banco de dados.

Como falei, alguma coisa não me cheira bem... Sinto que essa abordagem me trará problemas futuros, não me sinto confortável com isso:

```
mesaBL.TransferirItens(mesaOrigem, mesaDestino, itensIds);
```

Sinto que minha aplicação não está bem estruturada à mudanças.

Agradeço desde já pela atenção dos senhores.

Aqui um pouco de código:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    private readonly IContaMesaComandaItemBL _contaMesaComandaItemBL;

    public FooViewModel(IContaMesaComandaItemBL contaMesaComandaItemBL)
    {
        _contaMesaComandaItemBL = contaMesaComandaItemBL;
    }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    // Outras propriedades, comandos, métodos, etc...


    public void RemoverItemExecute()
    {
        _contaMesaComandaItemBL
            .DeletePorId(ItemId)
            .Subscribe(removido =>
            {
                // Item removido com sucesso
            },
            ex =>
            {
                // Erro
            });
    }
}

public class ContaMesaComandaItemBL : BLBase<ContaMesaComandaItem>, IContaMesaComandaItemBL
{
    public ContaMesaComandaItemBL(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory) : base(unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
    }

    public IObservable<bool> DeletePorId(int id)
    {
        return Observable.Create<bool>(obs =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
                {
                    var repository = unitOfWork.ContaMesaComandaItemRepository;
                    repository.Delete(e => e.ComandaItemPizzaMaeId == id);
                    repository.Delete(e => e.ContaMesaComandaItemId == id);
                    obs.OnNext(unitOfWork.Save() > 0);
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obs.OnError(ex);
            }
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

**Um pouco mais de código:**

```
public class ContaMesaBL : BLBase, IContaMesaBL
{
    public ContaMesaBL(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory) : base(unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
    }

    public IObservable AdicionarComanda(int contaMesaId, ContaMesaComanda comanda)
    {
        return Observable.Create(obs =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
                {
                    var contaMesaRepository = unitOfWork.ContaMesaRepository;
                    var conta = contaMesaRepository.First(c => c.ContaMesaId == contaMesaId);
                    conta.DataMovimento = DateTime.Now;
                    conta.ContaMesaComandas.Add(comanda);
                    unitOfWork.Save();
                    obs.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                obs.OnError(ex);
            }
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: eu particularmente não faço BLL ...

Comment: sem ver mais do código é difícil opinar, mas camada, componente, qualquer que seja a estratégia, desde que separe isso da apresentação e do banco parece bem, não precisa necessariamente ser uma camada BLL, pode ser um componente... lembre que de nada adianta separar as camadas se o modelo for o mesmo (a classe sai do banco e vai parar na view)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic E como você lida com as regras de negócio? Deixa ela na ViewModel/Controller? Eu tenho um cenário onde preciso trabalhar com mais de um repositório para persistir um modelo. Eu tenho um cenário onde essas regras de negócio serão compartilhadas futuramente com outro módulo.

Comment: Então falta código, falta um exemplo minimo, mas, eu praticamente não utilizo BLL é o que acredito não ser necessário. mas, realmente sem código minimo fica dificil propor algo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Adicionei um exemplo de código

Comment: @RicardoPontual Editei a pergunta e adicionei um pouco de código

Comment: nos projetos que trabalhei que tinha uma BL, ela ficava vazia na maioria dos casos, a presentation passava um objeto pra ela, e na maioria das vezes essa passava pra DL (repository, etc), mas ela ao menos separa a presentation de ir diretamente na DL, agora tem que ver se tem regras de sua responsabilidade lá... no seu exemplo, o fato de fazer esses dois deletes, é uma condição de negócio ou do modelo de dados, tipo FK? se for de dados, não deveria estar ai...estou comentanto só pra perceber se está com o código no lugar que é de sua responsabilidade

Comment: @RicardoPontual Seria uma FK, realmente esse código parece não estar no local apropriado... Agora tenho outros cenários, por exemplo, ao inserir uma Comanda preciso alterar o estado da Conta e de outras entidades, mas preciso garantir que essa operação ocorra de forma atômica... Esse código seria apropriado estar na BLL? As vezes também me pergunto se valeria a pena ter todo esse trabalho... Adicionei outro código de exemplo.

Comment: esse segundo exemplo que falou, IMHO faz todo sentido estar na BL e garantir que é um processo atômico (UnitOfWork, TransactionScope, etc). Se sua aplicação tem esse tipo de lógica de negócio faz sentido uma BL ou outra layer/component qualquer pra separra isso, e **principalmente** garantir que isso pode ser testado separadamente, isso pra mim é a grande vantagem de separar a camada, e como seu código injeta o `IUnitOfWorkFactory` isso fica fácil escrever um unit test pra garantir que essa regra está ok;)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar classes paralelas de validação e pode usar uma lib como [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) para adicionar as regras que deseja aplicar e validar antes de processar algo.